# how to covert an .xproj file into .csproj file?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, csproj

I am trying to build repository on linux/mono (autofac project). It contain .xproj file, but I am unable to build it with xbuild. How to convert xproj into .csproj ? (If there is no any tool, then i will recreate csproj from nothing or from older version (if there is one), but i want to know about automated translation)

Comment: Yu should check the answer. Do nothing but wait till Microsoft solves that.

Answer (score 0):

.xproj is an MSBuild file for dnx projects. It's a partial replacement for the csproj file. The dependencies have been moved out altogether to a project.json file, leaving just the build instructions in the xproj file.

Look at this:
http://ivanz.com/2016/05/17/farewell-project-json-hello-msbuild-and-csproj

Comment: upstream shoud look at that. I should use what upstream provide. And it is xproj. So I have no choice